# Setting up textarea to consume all the available space in a div (minus N pixels at the top)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set up a custom toolbar for a textarea, I have the following

**html**:

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="toolbar"></div>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

**css**:

```
#main {
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

#toolbar {
  background-color: #444;
  height: 40px;
  color: white;
}

textarea {
  outline: none; 
  border: none;
  border-left: 1px solid #777;
  border-right: 1px solid #777;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

It works exactly as I expected in Chrome, but in firefox / ie the text area is not consuming all the available space in the div.

How do I set it up so the toolbar takes up 40px at the top of the div, and the textarea consumes all the rest of the height.

I am sizing this stuff dynamically so **can not use a "px" height or width for the textarea**.

Codepen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pDgvq

Comment: This is bizarre - it works for any other block elements but not textareas in IE and Firefox. I wonder why...

Comment: Have you tried explicitly {{{box-sizing: border-box;}}} for the Textarea, maybe there is a different handling of textareas in FF/IE than in GC?

Comment: @BastianRang box sizing border box, seems to make no diff in IE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Better Suggestion

Set the textarea's width and height to 100%. Then, give it a 40px top-border that is transparent (color doesn't really matter, actually). Be sure to set box-sizing to border-box. Now position the relative toolbar on a higher z-index - voila.

Pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nFfam

#### Oldie

Rather than moving the textarea down, move the toolbar up:

```
#main {
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: 200px; width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
}

#toolbar {
  background-color: #444;
  height: 40px; width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mEGyp

Comment: You should probably save it as a fork copy or something. I'm seeing the same URL as in the question.

Comment: this could possibly work, side effect is that I can not inherit background from the container though ... I like the solution, creative

Comment: @SamSaffron If necessary, you could set the border-top on the container to 40px, and use it as your inherited background... I feel dirty now.

Comment: crap, in my app I can not do that ... already stuck sizing the wrapper 100%

Comment: @SamSaffron I think I have a far better solution - check the prepended alternative.

Comment: accepting this, as filthy as this hack is, it seems to totally work, love it, super duper creative, never thought I would use borders this way

Answer (score 3):

Both Firefox and IE9+ [support](http://caniuse.com/calc) the [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/calc) CSS function (you're out of luck with IE8 though; not sure what you're supporting).

I've added these lines to the `textarea`'s CSS in your pen ([updated version](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bDzEx)):

```
width: calc(100% - 2px);
height: calc(100% - 41px);
padding: 0;
```

The padding is just for normalization; you can choose whatever suits your needs, but be sure to adjust the pixel values in `calc()` accordingly. The `2px` for width are to compensate the left and right border; the `41px` for height are 40 for the toolbar and 1 for the bottom border.

Answer (score 1):

Add `width:-moz-available; height:100%;resize: none;` to `textarea`

```
 textarea {
  outline: none; 
  border: none;
  border-left: 1px solid #777;
  border-right: 1px solid #777;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;  width:-moz-available; height:100%; 
  resize: none;  
}
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TFQxX/3/)**

---

**Another Method**

You can add a div around textarea and give position:absolute to the div

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="toolbar"></div>

  <div id="container">
  <textarea></textarea>
  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container{ 
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  top:40px; 
  width:100%
}
textarea {
  outline: none; 
  border: none;
  border-left: 1px solid #777;
  border-right: 1px solid #777;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
  resize: none;  height:100%; width:99.5%
}
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/TFQxX/6/)**

Comment: This causes the textarea to stretch beyond the remaining height of the div because the toolbar is taking up the first 40px at the top.

Comment: I said height, not width. There's no difference in your updated demo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use height and width for textarea in % also apply top to the toolbar div in %
e.g. If top is 10% give 90% height to textarea.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is your desired result: [Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dJelL)

```
#main {
  background-color: #ddd;
  width: 400px; height: 200px; 
  padding: 0;
}

div #toolbar {
  background: #444;
  width: 100%; height: 40px;
}

textarea {
  margin: 0; 
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
}
```